# Hiding lists in html/css/bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, list, hide

So I'm learning web development on my own since I'm a CS major and it appears that my school doesn't have an option for that in cs (IT only). Right now I've been using youtube, Microsoft virtual academy, codecademy(not pro), and khan academy. Kind of besides the point but my question is I have pills in bootstrap, I want to have a list under each pill that's only accessable by clicking on that pill. The way I have it setup is that the pill is a shortcut to the list that is further down the page, is there a way for me to hide the lists so that they're only specific to the active pill without me having add each lists down the page, using html,css, or bootstrap? This is what I've been working with, I haven't moved on to js or php or any scripting, I do know python but I don't know how to implement scripts in html yet. 
code below

```
<ul class = "nav nav-pills">
    <li class ="active"><a href="#engineering-positions"> Engineering </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Medical </a></li>
    <li><a href="#edu-list"> Education </a></li>
    <li><a href="#"> Jobs for students </a></li>
    </div>
  </div>

<div class ="eng-company-list">
  <div class = "container">
  <ul id="engineering-positions">
    <li> Google </li>
    <li> Amazon </li>
    <li> Facebook </li>
    <li> Twitter </li>
    <li> Pandora </li>
    <li> Dropbox </li>
    <li> Pinterest </li>
    <li> Khan Academy </li>
    <li> Zynga </li>
    <li> EA </li>
    <li> Sony </li>
    <li> Intel </li>
  </ul>
  </div>
</div>


<div class ="edu-list">
  <div class ="container">
    <ul id = "edu-positions">
      <li> newitem </li>
      <li> newitem </li>
      <li> newitem </li>
      <li> newitem </li>
      <li> newitem </li>
      <li> newitem </li>
    </div>
</div>
```

like right now I click on the Engineering pill and it displays the eng-position list AND the edu-positions list, what I want to do is hide the edu-positions list from engineering and subsequently Jobs for students, Medical, etc.

Comment: You're not going to be able to do this with just CSS (unless you use some really advanced input:checked and adjacent sibling selectors.  You're going to need javascript.  Also, be sure to close your `ul` tags.

Comment: so I should learn js concurrently?

Comment: It's probably a good idea to first learn HTML/CSS to get the general layout / design under control first.  Once you're happy with that, then you can learn / add Javascript.  However, it's very possible to create a fully functioning site without Javascript.

Comment: Thanks for the advice I'll do that but for now I just made 5 separate pages with the exact same HTML except they have different lists and the pills that are clicked link to these pages.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the display: none; css property: value pair on a default element and psuedo classes.

For example, name each container uniquely. (e.g. engineering-container, edu-container) and set css property "display" to "none" on both. Use relative positioning in your css and define the positions in which the container will reside. You can also use x-index values to place the container behind your main container.

Then use the :hover pseudo class on your primary navbar and the hidden containers to make it show. Set the :hover display values to block. So when you hover over the navbar tag "engineering", the list will also expand and show for the list you've associated with the engineering navbar link.

Sorry for not giving you a step-by-step details, but it can be done with just css. It would be easier with jQuery. But as the remark made in an earlier comment, you should learn css layout first. It will make you a better developer and you will need to know it pretty well if you're going to become a developer.

So, since you don't know js, I highly recommend you look into CSS psuedo classes. With it, you can get a navigation list to expand and retract. You will have to just make sure that the :hover includes your links else it will retract once you move off the div because it no longer the active element.

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:**

```
<header id="navigation" class="nav nav-pills">
  <ul class="menu-content" style="display: none;">
    <li class="menu-link active"><a href="#">Engineering</a></li>
    <li class="menu-link"><a href="#">Medical</a></li>
  </ul>
</header>
```

And at end of body tag paste this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function showhide() {
    var nav = document.getElementbyId('navigation');
    if(nav.style.display == 'none') {
      nav.style.display = 'block';
    } else {
      nav.style.display = 'none';
    }
  }
</script>
```

Or I found 100% open-source example of navigation which you want by Bootstrap on github https://github.com/BlackrockDigital/startbootstrap-logo-nav.